# Select element in a frame

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, frames, tampermonkey

My goal is to change a value from `a` to `d` inside the array `options` in `menu.html` using Greasemonkey extension in Firefox but ***my problem is that the element I am trying to select/access is loaded as a frame***.

I have been trying to solve this issue for some time now and I would be very happy if someone could help me out.

---

I have got two files `main.html` and `menu.html` whose contents are:

`main.html` (is the main page)

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">

    <script language="javascript">
        document.writeln("<frameset rows='89,*,15' border='0' frameborder='0' framespacing='0'>");

        // here is the menu frame
        document.writeln("<frame src='menu.html' name='menufrm' frameborder='no' border='0' scrolling='no' target='_self' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' noresize>");

        document.writeln("</frameset>");

    </script>

</head>

</html>
```

`menu.html` (is loaded "through" a frame)

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Pragma' content='no-cache'>

    <link rel=stylesheet href='stylemain.css' type='text/css'>
    <script language='javascript' src='menuBcm.js'></script>

    <base target="_self">
</head>

<body class='mainMenuBody' topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="1000">

        <tr>
            <td class='menu' width="170" valign="top" align="left">

                <script language='javascript'>
                    var options = new Array('a',
                        'b',
                        'c');

                    // ultimate goal is to change the value of a to d above before 
                    // execution of the script below     

                    createBcmMenu(options); // from  menuBcm.js
                    initializeDocument();
                </script>

            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Which looks something like this:

```
+----------------------------+  
| main page (192.168.1.1)    |  
|                            |  
|  +---------------------+   |  
|  | frame (192.168.1.1) |   |  
|  +---------------------+   |  
|                            |   
+----------------------------+
```

**Greasemonkey script:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        a-to-d
// @namespace   namespace
// @include     http://192.168.1.1/main.html
// @include     http://192.168.1.1/menu.html
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

var newScript = `var options = new Array('d','b','c');` ;

// somehow select that element below
document.(!).innerHTML = newScript; // (!): somehow select script element in menu.html
```

Comment: frames have been deprecated for years...why are you needing frames in the first place?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am not the author of that original code and don't have the ability to change the code to remove the frames.

Answer (score 2):

You can access  frame window using `window.frames.menufrm`

Then do things like:

```
var frm = window.frames.menufrm;    
frm.options = ['d','b','c'];
frm.createBcmMenu(options);
```

No guarantees that calling the function again will work well but you can't change anything before that frame has loaded and the original function call will have already been run

Comment: Thank you for your input! But by running the code above I get `ReferenceError: options is not defined`