# Replaceing/swapping JavaScript file in html using Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, http-proxy, tampermonkey

My goal is to replace an original JavaScript file from a web-page with my home-made file that I have locally. I have found an interesting script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37149061/6130540) which I repurposed to fit my objective.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        JS_tamper
// @namespace   namespace
// @include     http://192.168.1.1/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

var newJSFile = "http://localhost:8080/tamper.js"; //The JS file to load in replacment of old JS file

var oldJSFile = "http://192.168.1.1/menuBcm.js"; //The old JS file as it is named in inspect element (make sure its spelled EXACTLY the same)

var pattern = new RegExp(oldJSFile, "i"); //Create the RegExp pattern with the /i switch to make it case-insensitive

function injectScript(originalPage) { //Function injectScript replaces the file
    console.log('Replace stage 2: Replace text matching', oldJSFile, 'with', newJSFile);
    var moddedPage = originalPage.replace(pattern, newJSFile); //Modify the HTML code that we got, replacing the old JS file with the new one
    document.open();
    console.log('Replace stage 3: Write new HTML to page...');
    document.write(moddedPage); //Write to the page the new HTML code
    document.close();
}

setTimeout(function() { //Wait a bit for the page's HTML to load...
    console.log('Replace stage 1: target HTML');
    injectScript(document.documentElement.outerHTML); //Run function injectScript with the page's HTML as oldPage in the function
}, 1111);
```

But the console log never reaches stage 3 presumably due to some kind of error opening ( `document.open()` )  the file or replacing ( `.replace`) the script.

Output:

```
//Replace stage 1: target HTML  JS_tamper.user.js:29:5
//Replace stage 2: Replace text matching "http://192.168.1.1/menuBcm.js" with "http://localhost:8080/tamper.js"
```

**Does anyone know why I am having this issue or perhaps another way of solving this problem using Greasemonkey(or other extension)?**

*I have created another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43442788/select-element-in-a-frame) with another (different) question on the same project if you are interested in some of the involved files.*

Comment: I thought the extension *Resource Override* proposed by [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35580407/9758790) may help.

Answer (score 1):

The original script was already executed before the `injectScript`, so even if your tampermonkey works as expected, the result may not be like what you need. Generally,You need a proxy server to achieve this.

If you don't want to build a proxy server, try to find something like `if(window.a)return;` in the original script, write `window.a=true` in your tampermoneky script, runs it at [document-start](http://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php?ext=dhdg#_run_at), and [insert your own script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121948/dynamically-add-script-tag-with-src-that-may-include-document-write)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Should I replace a from `window.a` with something?

Comment: @Clone  It's just an example. It depends on the content of the `oldJSFile` . You can even override some native api to raise an error in it.